# The difference between a destructor and 'delete'

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, delete-operator

What is the difference between the destruction of an object and deletion in C++? In OOP, when an object goes out of the scope, the destructor is called, and when dynamically allocating memory we have to use the `delete` keyword inside the destructor. So what does it mean for an object to be destroyed or deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A destructor is a special method for a `class`. It is called whenever an object goes out of scope, or someone calls it explicitly.

An example where an objects destructor is called, but no delete:

```
struct MyObject
{
    MyObject() { std::cout << "default constructor"; }
    ~MyObject() { std::cout << "destructor"; }
    void doWork() {};
}

int main()
{
    {
        MyObject object; //constructor is called and memory allocated for the object on the stack
        object.doWork();
    } //at the end of scope, the destructor of MyObject is called, and the stack memory is "released"
    // object is not longer available and stack memory is free
}
```

An example when scope does not help you:

```
int main()
{
    {
        MyObject* object_ptr = new MyObject; //constructor is called and memory allocated on the heap. The pointer_ptr object 
        object_ptr->doWork();
    } //at the end of scope the object_ptr is removed from the stack, but the destructor for the MyObject is not called!
    // object_ptr is no longer available.
}
```

For the above example, we have an issue with the dynamically allocated memory. We *explicitly* call the destructor of the object we are *pointing to* by calling delete (and freeing the memory where MyObject is residing!):

```
int main()
{
    {
        MyObject* object_ptr = new MyObject; //constructor is called and memory allocated on the heap. The pointer_ptr object 
        object_ptr->doWork();
        delete object_ptr; // destructor of MyObject is called and memory freed.
        // object_ptr is still usable here, but it is pointing at an destroyed object, so don't use it! (unless you redirect it)
    } 
}
```

So `delete` is for managing the dynamic memory, but the destructor is a method of the class itself, which is always called when the object is getting freed from the memory (stack or heap). The destructor is called when freeing the memory for the object, so that *if* the object itself handles memory, is has time to release that memory. That's why smart pointers are good:

```
int main()
{
    {
        std::unique_ptr<MyObject> object_ptr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(); //constructor is called and memory allocated on the heap. The pointer_ptr object 
        object_ptr->doWork();
    }  //destructor for std::unique_ptr<MyObject> is called, which in turn calls delete on the object it is pointing at, which calls the destructor of that object!
}
```

Comment: Note: if you want to be really fancy, you can do placement news and call destructors explicitly

Comment: @ JVApen Yeah, had to stop somewhere. I added unique_ptr only to show the use case where it makes sense to call destructor of an object that is handling memory.

Comment: @MikaelH, do you mean when an object goes out of scope, it is destructed and the memory, for that object,  is not deleted meaning it can be used again. But in case of deletion, the memory is not valid until we reallocate it again, am I right?

Comment: @slahOmar Memory is never deleted but freed. So for an object on the heap, the memory where the object was residing, is marked free so that we can reuse that memory section again. And correctly, we cannot use that memory before it is occupied again. An object that goes out of scope only gets destructed if it is on the stack, (unless an object is calling delete from the destructor).

Comment: But the memory on the stack never gets "freed" in that sense. The memory allocation is automatically handled. Whenever we enter a scope, the stack shifts and puts new objects on top. When we go out of scope, the stack shifts back and objects that were on top of the stack are not longer reachable.

Comment: @MikaelH say we have two variables one od them is reference variable  'int x and int& y = x' they are pointing to the same address when  'y'  goes out of scope, it is removed and the stack memory is 'released' as you said. the second  variable , x, is still pointing to a valid memory, and we can use it, though the meomry is released ! how is that ?

Comment: Although `y` in `int& y = x` is a alias to x, it is basically a pointer to x in memory. So `x` needs to be initialized firstly, and it is put on the stack. `y` is put on the stack and is pointing at the memory location of `x`. So as long as `y` is on the stack, we can call `x` through it. When `y` is out of scope, the *memory of the pointer that points to x* (`y`) is freed, but `x` itself is still untouched. So you can still use `x` without problems.

Comment: @MikaelH, great  I got it finally thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for memory allocation some of them are:

1. Automatic memory allocation :
   In this case ,the variables defined inside a scope ,for example functions, are automatic allocated, and is usually stored on the stack. You have a limited control over the lifetime of this memory. E.g: automatic variables in a function are only there until the function finishes, then when going out of that scope, their **destructor**s are called automatically i.e. you must not call **delete** to free the memory reserved for that object.
2. Dynamic memory allocation :
   In this case , the variables defined inside a scope ,for example functions, are dynamically allocated. You control the size and the lifetime of these memory locations. If you don't free the reserved memory (**delete** it), the allocated memory is still valid and accessible, even though the function terminated (went out of scope) and in this case you'll have memory leakage, which may cause the program to crash. So the object should be **delete** explicitly which in turn will call the **destructor** for that object.

Comment: Worth saying I think that the reclaiming the memory for automatically allocated variables and the destruction of those variables are two different processes. The destructor for an automatic variable is called when it goes out of scope. But the memory may be reclaimed at a later date, for instance when the function containing the variable is exited.

Comment: @john what do you mean by "reclaiming"

Comment: I mean the memory on the stack becoming available for other variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that a constructor is only *part* of the process of creating an object, invoking the destructor is just *part* of the process of destroying an object. It is a place where special clean-up code can go, like closing file handles or destroying other, indirectly-owned objects.

`delete` is the way you trigger the deletion of a dynamically allocated object. Other types of object are deleted automatically when they go out of scope. This keyword will clean up memory and more abstractly end the object's lifetime so that the compiler knows it doesn't conceptually "exist" any more.

You generally don't call the destructor manually, as it is usually insufficient for safely ending the lifetime of an object on its own. However, doing so is useful when you're taking super-fine-grained control over objects' existences, with (for example) placement `new`: then, it *can* be sufficient. But this is a special case.

Answer (score -1):

When an object is destroyed it's destructor is called. A **pointer** to a dynamically allocated memory can be deleted, objects themselves can't be deleted (unless you think of a pointer as a kind of object).

Either of these actions can have knock on effects that cause the other action to happen (or more instances of the same action). For instance if you delete a pointer to an object, then the objects destructor will be called (if it has one) and it's destructor may cause other pointers to be deleted and other objects to be destroyed.

Basically destructor is about the death of objects and deletion is about the freeing of dynamically allocated memory, but the two actions are often intertwined.

Comment: so what happens when normal variables such as 'int x = 5' goes out of scope ?is it deleted or destroyed?

Comment: The object which a pointer points to can be deleted not the pointer itself! The object itself can be deleted by calling delete on its pointer.

Comment: @slahOmar It's destroyed, but since `int` doesn't have a destructor nothing actually happens.

Comment: @Klaus We both know what the situtation but I think 'The object itself can be deleted by calling delete on its pointer' is a confusing way of putting it. You delete the pointer, the consequence is that the object is destroyed and the memory is freed.

Comment: I believe that is bad wording because the pointer itself is not deleted. I would please you to make it more clear! You call delete with the pointer but the semantic is *not* "delete the pointer" as I read from your answer.